# How to get ClientHello information during SSL handshake in JAVA

Tags: java, ssl, handshake, jsse

I want to get something like client compression_methods or client supported cipher Suites from ssl handshake
I have tried using

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String serverKeyStoreFile = "D:\\tomcat.keystore";
    String serverKeyStorePwd = "logiscn";
    String catServerKeyPwd = "logiscn";
    String serverTrustKeyStoreFile = "D:\\tomcat.keystore";
    String serverTrustKeyStorePwd = "logiscn";
    //System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl,handshake");
    KeyStore serverKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    serverKeyStore.load(new FileInputStream(serverKeyStoreFile), serverKeyStorePwd.toCharArray());
    KeyStore serverTrustKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    serverTrustKeyStore.load(new FileInputStream(serverTrustKeyStoreFile), serverTrustKeyStorePwd.toCharArray());

    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    kmf.init(serverKeyStore, catServerKeyPwd.toCharArray());

    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    tmf.init(serverTrustKeyStore);
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
    // System.out.println(sslContext.getProvider());
    sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
    SSLServerSocketFactory sslServerSocketFactory = sslContext.getServerSocketFactory();
    SSLServerSocket sslServerSocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(SERVER_PORT);
    // sslServerSocket.setNeedClientAuth(true);

    while (true) {
        SSLSocket s = (SSLSocket) sslServerSocket.accept();
    //  System.out.println(s);
        //System.out.println(s.getClass());
        // s.getSupportedProtocols()
        CatServer cs = new CatServer(s);
        //s.addHandshakeCompletedListener(cs);
        s.startHandshake();
        // System.out.println(s.getHandshakeSession().getProtocol());
        new Thread(cs).start();
    }
}
```

But SSLSocket doesn't contains the api to get such information.
I read the source code about jsse.jar ,found that 
During sslhandshake, SSLSocket use sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker to complete the whole processing and ServerHandshaker have newed an ClientHello to restore this things

```
    void processMessage(byte paramByte, int paramInt) throws IOException {
    if ((this.state >= paramByte) && (this.state != 16) && (paramByte != 15)) {
        throw new SSLProtocolException("Handshake message sequence violation, state = " + this.state + ", type = " + paramByte);
    }
    switch (paramByte) {
    case 1:
        HandshakeMessage.ClientHello localClientHello = new HandshakeMessage.ClientHello(this.input, paramInt);
        clientHello(localClientHello);
        break;
    case 11:
        if (this.doClientAuth == 0) {
            fatalSE((byte) 10, "client sent unsolicited cert chain");
        }
        clientCertificate(new HandshakeMessage.CertificateMsg(this.input));
        break;
    case 16:
        SecretKey localSecretKey;
        switch (this.keyExchange) {
        case K_RSA:
        case K_RSA_EXPORT:
            RSAClientKeyExchange localRSAClientKeyExchange = new RSAClientKeyExchange(this.protocolVersion, this.clientRequestedVersion,
                    this.sslContext.getSecureRandom(), this.input, paramInt, this.privateKey);

            localSecretKey = clientKeyExchange(localRSAClientKeyExchange);
            break;
        case K_KRB5:
        case K_KRB5_EXPORT:
            localSecretKey = clientKeyExchange(new KerberosClientKeyExchange(this.protocolVersion, this.clientRequestedVersion,
                    this.sslContext

                            .getSecureRandom(),
                    this.input,

                    getAccSE(), this.serviceCreds));

            break;
        case K_DHE_RSA:
        case K_DHE_DSS:
        case K_DH_ANON:
            localSecretKey = clientKeyExchange(new DHClientKeyExchange(this.input));
            break;
        case K_ECDH_RSA:
        case K_ECDH_ECDSA:
        case K_ECDHE_RSA:
        case K_ECDHE_ECDSA:
        case K_ECDH_ANON:
            localSecretKey = clientKeyExchange(new ECDHClientKeyExchange(this.input));
            break;
        default:
            throw new SSLProtocolException("Unrecognized key exchange: " + this.keyExchange);
        }
        calculateKeys(localSecretKey, this.clientRequestedVersion);
        break;
    case 15:
        clientCertificateVerify(new HandshakeMessage.CertificateVerify(this.input, getLocalSupportedSignAlgs(), this.protocolVersion));
        break;
    case 20:
        if (!receivedChangeCipherSpec()) {
            fatalSE((byte) 40, "Received Finished message before ChangeCipherSpec");
        }
        clientFinished(new HandshakeMessage.Finished(this.protocolVersion, this.input, this.cipherSuite));
        break;
    default:
        throw new SSLProtocolException("Illegal server handshake msg, " + paramByte);
    }
    if (this.state < paramByte) {
        if (paramByte == 15) {
            this.state = (paramByte + 2);
        } else {
            this.state = paramByte;
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is I can't get HandshakeMessage.ClientHello from sslsocket object.

Comment: Why? You can get the *actual* cipher suite from the `SSLSession`, *after* it has been negotiated by JSSE. Why do you think you need to know the client's supported cipher suites?

Comment: In fact you appear to be trying to implement the SSL key negotiation nnhasephase. Why? It's already done for you. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP  I am trying to create a website which can detect what cipher suites and compression mode the browser support like [website1](https://www.howsmyssl.com/) and [website2](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html)

Comment: I am not sure if it could success in java,I have learned about that apache mod could do this,but it's diffcult for me to write c code

Answer (score 0):

It looks theoretically possible but I haven't seen any ready to use Java code. Have a look at the [JSSE Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#ClientHelloParser) at part "Preparing the ClientHello Parser" which gives the beginning of a solution to your problem.

Comment: It's a good idea to set up a proxy socket server,I will try it,thanks a lot,Adell